# Nesting queries in SQL

Tags: sql, nested

The goal of my query is to return the country name and its head of state if it's headofstate has a name starting with A, and the capital of the country has greater than 100,000 people utilizing a nested query.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT country.name as country, 
       (SELECT country.headofstate 
        from country 
        where country.headofstate like 'A%')      
from country, city 
where city.population > 100000;
```

I've tried reversing it, placing it in the where clause etc. I don't get nested queries. I'm just getting errors back, like "subquery returns more than one row" and such. If someone could help me out with how to order it, and explain why it needs to be a certain way, that'd be great.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If it has to be "nested", this would be one way, to get your job done:

```
SELECT o.name AS country, o.headofstate 
FROM   country o
WHERE  o.headofstate like 'A%'
AND   (
    SELECT i.population
    FROM   city i
    WHERE  i.id = o.capital
    ) > 100000
```

A `JOIN` would be more efficient than a correlated subquery, though. Can it be, that who ever gave you that task is not up to speed himself?

Comment: If i use this kind of sql Query then it is showing me the error as below. Operand should contain 1 column(s) Can you Help me.... My Sql Query is  SELECT s.* 
FROM   j5749_faculty_subjects as s
WHERE  s.subjectid='1'
AND   (
  SELECT a.*
  FROM   j5749_facultyavailablity as a
  WHERE  a.facultyid = s.facultyid AND a.timeid='3'
    )

Comment: @amit: See the last part in my query: `> 100000`. You have no equivalent. You probably want `EXISTS`. [See this example.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251180/find-records-where-join-doesnt-exist/14260510#14260510) Else, start a *new question* with all the details.

Comment: Neat, looks like you can do it in the `FROM` clause too! -- just nest a query inside of parenthesis, and name it -- then you can reference it like a table from your `SELECT`, `WHERE` and `JOIN` clauses, etc. (e.g. `SELECT s.* FROM (SELECT [blah] FROM [blaz] WHERE [foo]) AS s WHERE s.whatever = 'foop'`.)

Answer (score 8):

You need to `join` the two tables and then filter the result in `where` clause:

```
SELECT country.name as country, country.headofstate 
from country
inner join city on city.id = country.capital
where city.population > 100000
and country.headofstate like 'A%'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help again! And although this works perfectly, and makes sense, I am supposed to be using nested queries. Do you have an alternative?

Comment: @ZAX if you need a nested query, take a look at my answer ... :-)

Comment: @ZAX Dare I ask why, on earth, are you **suppposed** to use nested queries? Is this homework? Because nested queries are not even the best solution for this problem

Comment: I"m reading an sql book. I don't think I"m at that point of using inner joins yet necessarily although I have some background and understand what you're doing with the query. I guess its trying to "bring me along" if you will.

Comment: @ZAX `Inner joins` are just explicit joins. If you need to query for data that are in 2 different tables, the best option (in performance and readability) is to join, regardless whether implicitly or explicitly

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it, the only place for a nested query would be in the WHERE clause, so e.g.

```
SELECT country.name, country.headofstate
FROM country 
WHERE country.headofstate LIKE 'A%' AND 
country.id in (SELECT country_id FROM city WHERE population > 100000)
```

Apart from that, I have to agree with Adrian on: why the heck should you use nested queries?

Answer (score 1):

Query below should help you achieve what you want.

```
select scountry, headofstate from data 
where data.scountry like 'a%'and ttlppl>=100000
```