# Find records where join doesn't exist

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a scope to limit all `questions` by whether or not a user has voted on them. In the model:

```
scope :answered_by, lambda {|u| joins(:votes).where("votes.user_id = ?", u.id) }
scope :unanswered_by, lambda {|u| joins(:votes).where("votes.user_id != ?", u.id) }
```

In the controller, I call them like this:

```
@answered = Question.answered_by(current_user)
@unanswered = Question.unanswered_by(current_user)
```

The unanswered_by scope is incorrect. I essentially want to find where there is no vote. Instead, it is trying to look for if there is a vote that doesn't equal the current user. Any ideas how to return all records where a join doesn't exist?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use an [**`EXISTS`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) expression:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM votes v  -- SELECT list can be empty
   WHERE  v.some_id = base_table.some_id
   AND    v.user_id = ?
   )
```

#### The difference

... between `NOT EXISTS()` (Ⓔ) and `NOT IN()` (Ⓘ) is twofold:

1. *Performance*

   Ⓔ is generally faster. It stops processing the subquery as soon as the first match is found. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS)

   > The subquery will generally only be executed long enough to determine
   >   whether at least one row is returned, not all the way to completion.

   Ⓘ can also be optimized by the query planner, but to a lesser extent since `NULL` handling makes it more complex.
2. *Correctness*

   If one of the resulting values in the subquery expression is `NULL`, the result of Ⓘ is `NULL`, while common logic would expect `TRUE` - and Ⓔ will return `TRUE`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-NOTIN)

   > If all the per-row results are either unequal or null, with at least
   >   one null, then the result of `NOT IN` is null.

Essentially, `(NOT) EXISTS` is the better choice in most cases.

#### Example

Your query can look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   questions q
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT FROM votes v 
    WHERE  v.question_id = q.id
    AND    v.user_id = ?
    );
```

Do *not* join to `votes` in the base query. That would void the effort.

Besides `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN` there are additional syntax options with `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` and `EXCEPT`. See:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Comment: not sure if there is a difference between yours and shweta's solutions, but also works

Comment: @Marc: I added a rationale for my suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it worked, but ran some tests and it's not returning all the unanswered questions:

SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" INNER JOIN "votes" ON "votes"."question_id" = "questions"."id" WHERE (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM votes WHERE user_id = ?))

Comment: @Marc: I added a version of your query that should work to my answer. I also clarified the original code example to reflect that you want an answer *per row* in the base table.

Comment: Hurray! `NOT IN` will never be more correct and can never be faster than the corresponding `NOT EXISTS`. essentially, `NOT IN` is evil. ( I just don't like the word *anti-pattern* )

Comment: But, Captain @wildplasser! There *are* cases where you *want* the `NULL`. Only they are few and far between.

Comment: There is an additional performance-issue: `NOT IN` has to remove duplicates (read: sort), including the dreaded NULLS. (smart planners (==simple plans) may know when not to sort, though) I still have to find a case where `IN` is actually needed. `NOT IN` is even worse ... (BTW: I think, I have a few `NOT IN`s in my sudoku solver. time for a rewrite ...)

Answer (score 2):

And if you want to do `EXISTS` query in elegant and Rails-ish manner, you can use [Where Exists](https://github.com/EugZol/where_exists) gem I've written:

```
Question.where_not_exists(:votes, user_id: current_user.id)
```

Of course, you can made scope of it as well:

```
scope :unanswered_by, ->(user){ where_not_exists(:votes, user_id: user.id) }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this and let me know if it works

**EDIT-1**

```
scope :unanswered_questions, lambda { joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN votes ON questions.id = votes.question_id').where('votes.question_id IS NULL') }
```

**EDIT-2**

```
scope :unanswered_by, lambda {|u| where("questions.id NOT IN (SELECT votes.question_id from votes where votes.user_id = ?)",u.id) }
```

Comment: I have updated the answer, now it will return all questions which have no answers

Comment: Seems to be closer. I'm trying to get unanswered questions for a particular user, which is the u variable. Any ideas how to check that the votes don't exist for a particular user?