# PostgreSQL import, if constraint not met set null

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, foreign-keys, referential-integrity

I'm trying to import a db from file-maker pro into PostgreSQL. As a result of not being maintained well, the data has had some degradation in links between tables over time.
I've attempted to import the data with no constraints and then add the constraint with a `USING` bock to set it to null if the referenced value doesn't exist.

I have two tables, a `people` table and a `show` table. I want to set all the people id's that don't exist to null in the `show_leader_id` column of the `show` table. Here's what I have:

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE show ADD FOREIGN KEY (show_leader_id) REFERENCES people 
    USING (CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM people WHERE person_id=show_leader_id)=1 THEN show_leader_id ELSE NULL END);
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check existence with an [`EXISTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) semi-join:

```
UPDATE show s
SET    show_leader_id = NULL
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM people WHERE person_id = s.show_leader_id);
```

Then add your fk constraint.
If you have concurrent write operations, run both in the same transaction [like @Eelke advises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24516905/939860). (But that's probably not the case in your situation.)

`NOT IN` can be treacherous if there are `NULL` values in `people.person_id`. Since you are dealing with a mess, this is not unlikely. Details:

- [Find records where join doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251180/find-records-where-join-doesnt-exist/14260510#14260510)
- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)