# sql query to extract new records

Tags: sql, postgresql, exists

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Company (
    CompanyUniqueID BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR (150) NOT NULL
 );

CREATE TABLE Item ( 
  ItemUniqueID BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  CompanyUniqueID BIGINT NULL REFERENCES company DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
  Name VARCHAR (150) NOT NULL,
  AddedDate TIMESTAMP without time zone DEFAULT now()
);
```

In the life time of the application new companies and items are added to the tables.
I wish to create an sql query that will select the "new added companies" from a given date
I've started with this query:

```
(Select * from company
 where companyuniqueid in (
   select distinct companyuniqueid from Item where AddedDate > '2014-10-25'))
```

The above is not good because items that were added after 2014-10-25 and belong to companies that already exist will be also selected.

For example, a snapshot of `Company` table from 2014-10-20 can look like this:

```
1 AAA
2 BBB
3 CCC
```

and table Items will look like:

```
1 1 111 2014-10-01
2 2 222 2014-10-10
3 2 333 2014-10-10
4 3 444 2014-10-15
```

on the 2014-10-26 the following records were added:

table company

```
4 DDD
```

table Items

```
5 1 555 2014-10-26
6 3 663 2014-10-26
7 4 777 2014-10-27
```

I've tried adding this to the query:

```
(Select * from company
 where companyuniqueid in (
    select distinct companyuniqueid from Item
    where AddedDate > '2014-10-25')
 and companyuniqueid not in (
    select distinct companyuniqueid from Item
    where AddedDate <= '2014-10-25'))
```

but I'm getting an empty result, what should be the query in order to receive only 4 DDD?

Comment: Is `AddedDate` *supposed* to allow NULL values? Strikes me as a candidate for a `NOT NULL` constraint.

Answer (score 2):

Use an [**`EXISTS`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) anti-semi-join. Typically fastest and cleaner than `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   company c
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   item
   WHERE  addeddate < '2014-10-25'
   AND    companyuniqueid = c.companyuniqueid);
```

This returns
*companies that have no items pre-dating a given date.*
including companies without items and possibly with items that have `addeddate IS NULL`.
To limit result to companies with new items, add:

```
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   item
   WHERE  addeddate >= '2014-10-25'
   AND    companyuniqueid = c.companyuniqueid)
```

But consider adding another column `added_date` to the table `company` to avoid ambiguities and simplify things.

#### Why did the original query not work?

Probably another case of **`NOT IN` with a set containing a `NULL` value**.
Your column `item.companyuniqueid` allows `NULL` values. Your subquery:

```
select distinct companyuniqueid from Item where AddedDate <= '2014-10-25'
```

... probably includes a `NULL` value. In that case, this expression is never `TRUE`:

```
companyuniqueid not in (<above subquery>)
```

Returns `FALSE` or `NULL` ("unknown") if the set includes a `NULL` value. But only `TRUE` would qualify as `WHERE` condition. So no row is returned.

[**Note** that the same is not true for an *empty set*.](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/24334.1288545554@sss.pgh.pa.us#24334.1288545554@sss.pgh.pa.us) If above subquery would return *no row*, the `NOT IN` expression would evaluate to `TRUE`, as long as the left side is `NOT NULL`.

Basically, avoid `NOT IN (<subquery>)` where you can. `NOT EXISTS` is almost always superior.
If you use it, know your way around `NULL` values. More details:

- [Find records where join doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251180/find-records-where-join-doesnt-exist/14260510#14260510)
- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Comment: @Gordon: A table alias for item is *not* necessary. The query is valid as is. Without table qualification `item.companyuniqueid` is visible first in the subquery.

Comment: I see you removed it.  I find such syntax without aliases on both sides to be dangerous.

Comment: In my example company #4 (DDD) was added and had an item #7 adding another column is not possible, client request

Comment: @liva: Consider the added explanation and links.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Unambiguously correct. The "danger" is in the eye of the beholder here.

Answer (score 1):

```
with min_added as
(
    select i.companyuniqueid, min(i.addeddate) as addeddate
      from item i
  group by companyuniqueid
)
select * from min_added where min_added.addeddate > '2014-10-26';
```

will give you the company ids for all companies with items added after the date specified (no company will be returned for any companies with items added before the date.)