# Update to toggle a boolean column in a single statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, query-optimization

How can I **combine** in a single *sql* statement both queries in the most effective way?

```
UPDATE TABLE_A a
SET a.is_active = FALSE
WHERE a.id IN (SELECT id FROM TABLE_B);
```

And the same but *toggle* the flag for the remaining `id`s:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A a
SET a.is_active = TRUE
WHERE a.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM TABLE_B);
```

Comment: Your second query doesn't toggle the value, it just sets it to true.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can do use a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A a
    SET a.is_active = (CASE WHEN a.id IN (SELECT id FROM TABLE_B)
                            THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE
                       END);
```

In Postgres, you would simplify this to:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A
    SET is_active = (id IN (SELECT b.id FROM TABLE_B b));
```

Answer (score 3):

In Postgres, you can use `LEFT JOIN` within an `UPDATE` statement with the following syntax:

```
UPDATE a 
SET a.is_active = CASE WHEN b.id IS NULL THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE
FROM TABLE_A a
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B b ON a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table_a a
SET    is_active = NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM table_b b WHERE b.id = a.id);
```

That's assuming both `id` columns are **`NOT NULL`**.

Else, rows with `table_a.id IS NULL` are **not updated** at all in your original, because `NULL` is neither `IN` nor `NOT IN` any set.

And if there are any `NULL` values in `table_b.id` **none** of your rows end up with `a.is_active = TRUE`, since `a.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM TABLE_B)` is either `FALSE` or `NULL` but never `TRUE` in that case. `NOT IN` is infamous for this kind of "trap". Related:

- [Find records where join doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251180/find-records-where-join-doesnt-exist/14260510#14260510)
- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

This query with `EXISTS` updates *all* rows. `table_a.id IS NULL` results in `is_active = TRUE`, just like for other IDs that are not found in `table_b`, and NULL values in `table_b.id` make no difference whatsoever.

`EXISTS` is also attractive in particular if there can be (many) duplicate values in `table_b.id` - better performance. `table_b.id` should be indexed in any case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join on the two tables, then a case statement to determine if there is a value in TABLE B:

```
CREATE TABLE #TABLE_A (Id int, is_active bit)
CREATE TABLE #TABLE_B (Id int)


INSERT INTO #Table_A 
    VALUES   (1, NULL)
            ,(2, NULL)
            ,(3, NULL)
            ,(4, NULL)

INSERT INTO #TABLE_B 
    VALUES (1),(3)


SELECT * FROM #TABLE_A

UPDATE a
    SET is_active = (CASE WHEN b.id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM    #TABLE_A a
            LEFT OUTER JOIN #TABLE_B b
                ON      a.id = b.Id

SELECT * FROM #TABLE_A
```